# Any python document defines how the best base is selected?

Tags: python

I'm trying to understand the algorithm in Cpython source code for best base type selection in multiple inheritance. I'm unfortunately lost in the code so would like to see if its intention has been well documented somewhere.

I'm a daily user of SystemVerilog for which there is a 1000+ page IEEE LRM for every and all its details. But I can't find the similar documentation for python.

P.S. below is the prototype for **best_base**:

```
/* Calculate the best base amongst multiple base classes.
   This is the first one that's on the path to the "solid base". */
static PyTypeObject *
best_base(PyObject *bases)
```

Comment: Python isn't anywhere near as well-specified as you're hoping.

Comment: Yeah, seems only its developer knows all details about it.